# dc.js rowchart Place of others not used

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

js a rowchart.
For hiding the "others" i use following:

```
chart.othersGrouper(null);
```

this hide the row others, but the place of this row is not used for the "normal" rows?
Is there an other way so that the normal rows can use the place od the other row?

I mean if i hide the Others bar on the row chart, i get one extra line which is not filled with data, it is blank.

The left chart is shown with the others the right chart others are hidden, but no new data appears.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to turn off capping with [.cap(Infinity)](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/CapMixin.html#cap__anchor)?

Comment: i have added the screenshoot for explaination

Comment: What do you expect to see there? You have capping turned on and the others group turned off. So there is nothing more to show. That’s why I suggested turning capping off.

Comment: I would expect to see a third line of data

Comment: From your screenshots it looks like you have `.cap(2)` set - if so, please try removing it. Otherwise, I would have to see your code to understand why it is not showing all the rows.

Comment: oh you are right thank you for pointing me twice to the cap function :D 
It was in an event (the resize event of the window) where i have recalced the height of the chart and calced the cap(newValue) - after checking in this function if others are displayed it works.